# How to store in variable function returning value (kivy properties)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
class Data(object):


def get_key_nicks(self):
    '''
    It returns key and nicks object
    '''
    file = open(self.key_address, 'rb')
    key = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    file = open(self.nicks_address, 'rb')
    nicks = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    return (key, nicks)
```

Above is the data api and function which i want to use in kivy

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

data = ObjectProperty(Data())
key, nicks = ListProperty(data.get_key_nicks())
```

it gives error like:  AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'get_key_nicks'

Answer (score 0):

Properties are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), which basically means they look like normal attributes when accessed from *instances* of the class, but at class level they are objects on their own. That's the nature of the problem here - at class level `data` is an ObjectProperty, even though if you access it from an instance of the class you'll get your `Data()` object that you passed in as the default value.

That said, I don't know what your code is actually trying to do, do you want `key` and `nicks` to be separate ListProperties?

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand a bit more on what you're trying to do?

I think all you actually need to do is:

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    data = ObjectProperty(Data())

    def get_key_nicks(self):
        return data.get_key_nicks()
```